# Safari request abrupts on "_self" redirect

Tags: reactjs, firefox, safari, fetch-api

My request interrupts in Safari and in Firefox after the external `_self` link redirect.

[here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwFFY.png)

Is there a way to keep this fetch after redirect (except `preventDefault()` and redirecting after the request has been completed)

```
 const handleLinkClick = useCallback(() => {
    fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api', {method: 'POST'})
  }, [])
  return (
    <a
      href="https://www.google.com/"
      onClick={handleLinkClick}
    >
      link
    </a>
  );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keep this fetch"?  Do you want a reference to the call or the data it returns?

Comment: that was bad example of mine, it should have been `post` method, I use this request for analytics purposes, will edit.